# Working with VC and MinGW

Tags: linux, visual-c++, png, cygwin, mingw

I'm trying to use a few open source libraries like libpng in my VC++ project. I've used them in Linux environment without problems, but I'm clueless about how to get them to work in the VC++ environment. Here's what I tried:

1. I installed the libpng for Win32 package from SF (I also installed zlib the same way btw). I can see png.h in Program Files\GnuWin32\include but when I include it, the compiler says it requires unistd.h. I know this is the header for POSIX system calls so Windows won't have it.
2. I installed Cygwin, but later realized it's only good for building linux source codes on windows using gcc, instead of using MS VC (or am I wrong?)
3. I installed MinGW, but it seems MinGW is designed for using gcc too (or am I wrong?). MinGW does come with unistd.h but this header references MinGW's sys/types.h which is from linux, and MSVC has its own different sys/types.h so the compiler doesn't know which to use. The two files define different things and neither can cover both, so including either is not enough to get the whole project compile.

To this point it seems like a quite stupid #include problem but I just can't figure out the right way to do. I'm really a cross-platfrom noob. Maybe I'm going the wrong way from beginning...

So how should I proceed? What is your standard way of using linux libraries in VC++?

By the way it is possible for me to build with gcc using MinGW or Cygwin to generate windows executables, but I'd really prefer being able to build with VC++ because of my existing code base. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you must download libpng.lib/dll and header files for MS VC.

If your package has folder structure something like GnuWin32, it is definitely not for MS VC.

Check out OpenCV distribution (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2/)

It contains VC build of libpng and other image format libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure this is a viable solution but it seems quite tedious having to look for specific Win32 builds for each open source libs I use. Why can't I build myself from source code? Isn't that the very point of open source? I'm sure there must be a more general solution ...

Comment: You know, typical open source libraries uses automatic config generation build tools don't support MS VC, so you must hand generate VC config and header files.It's difficult work to do.

Comment: Hmmm it's true that very few in the open source community cares about VC. I used to think most open source projects out there are platform-independent, but indeed they are not, right?

Comment: Platform independent true, but compiler independent are rare cases. Isn't it? :)

Comment: Sorry I'm confused again - Do you mean dependency issues like unistd.h are related to compiler independence? I thought it's about Linux vs Win32. If it's just about compiler, then I can build a Win32 lib out of the source using MinGW's gcc and then use the binary as static lib in VC. But my point is even if I have the Win32 lib, I still can't use the header because it references non-windows headers like unistd.h ...

Comment: I mean if it requires gcc, very much like it also requires full gcc build environment.

Answer (score 0):

common solution is to build such libraries by gcc (Cygwin or MinGW, doesn't matter), receive libs and link with them from VC project

Comment: Thanks. But I couldn't make that work. I can build with Cygwin but the header references linux-specific stuff like unistd.h so it can't be used in VC. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried that but as I explained in the original post, it conflicts windows' headers on sys/types.h. Basically both defines sys/types.h and neither works for the other environment. I don't know what I should do to get it compile.